# Г. Москва или г. Москвы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, ономастика

Я сделала для себя открытие. Полезла в интернет, уточнить, как все-таки правильно - ОВД такого-то района г. Москвы или г. Москва, а тут вон как, вопрос даже не в букве г. Оказывается "в городе Москве" - это правильно. Как же так и с каких пор так стало? В советской школе меня учили другому: либо "Я живу в городе Москва" (не склоняется), либо "Я живу в Москве" (склоняется). Вот с сокращением не знаю, как же правильно. А например, Правительство города Москвы - уже звучит вполне привычно. Что скажете?

Answer (score 4):

Склонение географических названий  действительно тема нелёгкая. Об этом можно прочитать [здесь](http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.

**Правильно: в городе Москве**, в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, в селе Шушенском, под хутором Михайловским; у реки Волги, долина ручья Сухого.

Склоняются обе части в наименовании Москва-река: Москвы-реки, на Москве-реке и т. д. В разговорной речи встречаются случаи несклоняемости первой части: за Москва-рекой, на Москва-реке и т. д. Но такое употребление не соответствует строгой литературной норме.

Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не склоняются в следующих случаях:

когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме мн. числа: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Мытищи;
когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: на реке Енисей, у реки Хопёр, в деревне Парфёнок (**однако это замечание не относится к сочетаниям со словом город**, поэтому правильно: в городе Туле, **из города Москвы**.

Answer (score 2):

Всегда было правильным склонять оба слова - в городе Москве. Лишь в последнее время из уст не очень грамотных людей стали звучать фразы "в городе Москва". Видимо, сказалось влияние названий иностранных городов, где склоняется только слово "город" или названий российских населенных пунктов, представляющих несклоняемые существительные: "в городе Сочи"