# Склонение словосочетания "город Москва"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Почему были произведены изменения - я поняла, а вот когда пришли к такому решению, не знаю.

Возможно, вы знаете?

Comment: О каких изменениях речь?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41138/%d0%93-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b3-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/%d0%92-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

> [Как все-таки правильно говорить: в городе Москве или в городе Москва?](https://skver.2gis.ru/moscow/question/kak-vse-taki-pravilno-govorit-v-gorode-moskve-ili-v-gorode-moskva/571dcd405f5e88d5108b4568)
>   Галина Мандрикова, доктор филологических наук, доцент, заведующая кафедрой филологии факультета гуманитарного образования НГТУ
>
> Это интересная история. По устоявшейся традиции все названия склоняются: в городе Москве, в городе Новосибирске, в городе Кемерове и так далее. Но во время Великой Отечественной войны, когда «Информбюро» Советского Союза передавало сводки с фронта, эта литературная норма поменялась: в целях точного произнесения названия городов, рек и прочих топонимов перестали склонять. То есть они должны были звучать так, чтобы никаких сомнений не оставалось, о каком, скажем, населённом пункте идёт речь. **С тех пор эти оба варианта – склоняемый и несклоняемый - существуют параллельно**. При этом те, кто не склоняет и говорит «я живу в городе Москва» чаще всего убеждены, что так нужно и так правильно. И наоборот. Хотя вообще-то правильно, конечно, склонять. Более того, говорить «в городе Москве/Москва» уже бессмысленно. Для топонимов употребление «город», «река», «посёлок» стали излишними. Особенно это касается столиц и крупных городов. Если человек хочет сказать, что он живёт в Москве, ему слово «город» вообще не надо использовать, потому что и так все знают, что Москва – это город. Уместно употреблять слова «река», «город» и так далее перед топонимом, если для собеседника это малознакомое место и ему нужно пояснить, что это за топоним. Вообще, «В городе Москва/Москве» - это отголоски канцелярского языка. Следование каким-либо нормам языка документов считается многими людьми правильным и красивым. Если же необходимо сокращённое написание, то правильно будет использовать склонённую форму – «в г. Москве».

Answer (score 0):

**Как склонять географические названия?**

[В городе Москва или в городе Москве? Названия в сочетании с родовым словом](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

**В Москве или в городе Москве?**

> В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой
>   указано, что «сокращение г. (город), как и полное слово, рекомендуется
>   употреблять ограниченно, главным образом перед названиями городов,
>   образованными от фамилий (г. Киров)».
>
> Таким образом, общеупотребительно: в Москве. Варианты в г. Москве, в
>   городе Москве  следует характеризовать как специфически канцелярские
>   (т. е. употребительные преимущественно в официально-деловой речи).
>   Варианты в г. Москва, в городе Москва не соответствуют литературной
>   норме.
>
> Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями
>   город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции
>   приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется,
>   если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет
>   собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.
>
> Правильно: *в городе Москве, в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города
>   Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, в селе Шушенском, под
>   хутором Михайловским; у реки Волги, долина ручья Сухого.*

Comment: А Вы точно поняли вопрос? Там спрашиваются какие-то даты, а я вообще не в курсе тех изменений.

Comment: Я так поняла, что хозяйка вопроса застала те времена, когда возможно (а может, и нужно) было произносить/писать *в городе Москва, городом Москва*... Дату перевоплощения Инет не фиксирует.

Comment: А такие времена точно были? (Я их, похоже, не застал.) Насколько я понял, автор вопроса знает, как правильно склонять, но интересуется чем-то совсем другим. Вряд ли Ваш ответ ей поможет.

Comment: Спасибо! Я, действительно , знаю, как склонять сейчас. Раньше нас учили так: в г.Москве, но в городе Москва.

Comment: Да, ещё небольшое дополнение: мне 70 лет.

Comment: Именно так до 60-х средняя школа и учила: склоняется одно слово — «в г. Москве» (сокращение указывает на имя собственное, оно не произносится читающим) и «в городе Москва» (в городе по имени Москва).

Answer (score 0):

> Почему были произведены изменения...

Скорее всего, Вы ошибаетесь. Мне ничего не известно о тех временах, когда считалось нормой альтернативное склонение. Ни в старых, ни в современных книгах о таких временах не упоминают. Если Вы где-то слышали, что раньше считалось нормой "в городе Москва", дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на это правило. (Ссылки на опечатки или ошибки в книгах и газетах давать не нужно, интересуют именно правила русского языка.)

**Дополнение.**
Поиском найти ничего не удалось. Однако сомнения возникли. Вот, например, [по этой ссылке](http://www.philology.nsc.ru/journals/spj/pdf/2016_3/%D1%D4%C6-2016-3.pdf) кандидат филологических наук Е.В. Генералова в статье, посвящённой вопросам, связанным с топонимами, много раз повторяет "в городе Москва" (и в других падежах тоже). Должно быть какое-то объяснение тому, что специалист в данном вопросе допускает подобные ошибки в научной работе. Одно из возможных объяснений — она использует источники прошлых лет и по невнимательности сохранила старое написание.

**Дополнение 2.**
Нашёл! Оказывается в школах до сих пор так учат. [Вот ссылка](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiYz8O2zajdAhUFXSwKHVxzCX8QFjADegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbb.dvfu.ru%2Fbbcswebdav%2Forgs%2FFU504UMKD%2F2013%2F%25D0%2593%25D0%259E%25D0%25A12%2F031000.62%2520%25D0%25A4%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25A0%25D0%25AF%25D0%259B%2F%25D0%25A3%25D0%259C%25D0%259A%25D0%2594%2F%25D0%25A4%25D0%25A2%25D0%2594.7%2520%25D0%259D%25D0%25B0%25D1%2583%25D1%2587%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D0%25B5%2520%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D1%258B%2520%25D1%2588%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D1%258C%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D0%25BE%2520%25D0%25BA%25D1%2583%25D1%2580%25D1%2581%25D0%25B0%2520%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D0%25BE%2520%25D1%258F%25D0%25B7%25D1%258B%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0.docx&usg=AOvVaw0jHxu16Q9yhedxCZvOskvc) (это прямая ссылка на Word-документ) на методические разработки для учителей, которые утверждены Министерством образования и науки. Там сказано, что некоторые географические названия являются исключением, и в качестве примера приводится предложение:

> Я живу в городе Москва.

Само собой разумеется, что эти методические разработки доходят до уровня школ. Сайтов с конкретными планами уроков, в которых повторяется это исключение из правил, много (по ним видно, что повторяется вся та методическая разработка). [Вот пример.](https://sites.google.com/site/russkijazykdla3klass/home/test-no-1)

**Моё личное мнение:** независимо от того, какими мотивами руководствуется Министерство, распространение в школе подобных правил не улучшает ситуацию с грамотностью, а способствует распространению хаоса и путаницы.

Comment: Жаль, что не сохранила учебники 50-х и 60-х годов. я училась в то время. .Русские по происхождению, но давно уже живущие заграницей, употребляют именно такое словосочетание: в городе Москва.

Comment: @Наталья Я попытался найти это в старых учебниках, но не смог. Я не исключаю, что это изменение могло произойти при реформе в 1956 г. Также не исключаю, что раньше просто не было зафиксировано никакое правило либо оно было слишком общим, а потом его конкретизировали.

Comment: Пожалуй, Вы правы.

Comment: @grizzly а что вообще такое "альтернативное склонение"? В отношении всякого рода методичек, то их сейчас только ленивый не пишет. Слава Богу, что вы не правы - 99% этого добра до школ не доходит.. Уже по той простой причине, что невозможно в одной школе пользоваться двумя взаимоисключающими пособиями.

Comment: И еще. А почему вы решили, что данный документ утвержден кем-то, кроме зав. кафедрой РЯ ДВФУ?!

Comment: @behemothus Точнее было бы сказать, что документ выпущен под эгидой Министерства. Я не знаю, есть ли здесь какая-то юридическая или даже семантическая разница. Если зав.кафедрой имеет право выпускать документы под эгидой Министерства, значит Министерство несёт за это ответственность.

Comment: Это не так. Максимум, что можно сказать: Документ выпущен в организации, входящей в структуру Минобра (или подчиняющейся ему). Канцелярские условности - не более.

Comment: @behemothus Я не возражаю. Для меня не так важна формулировка, как необходимость предупредить участников форума, что в некоторых школах опираются на этот документ. А также дать возможность ученикам, которые могут быть несправедливо наказаны в этих школах сослаться на это обсуждение.

Answer (score 0):

> Склонение словосочетания город Москва.

И. Город Москва
Р. Города Москвы
Д. Городу Москве
В. Город Москва
Т. Городом Москвой
П. (о) Городе Москве

*Во множественном склоняется только "город" (*Есть только один город Москва никаких **других городов Москва** не существует!*). Но обычно для топонимов этот вопрос выносят за скобки.*

> Почему были произведены изменения - я поняла, а вот, когда пришли к
>   такому решению, не знаю.

Расскажите, что это за изменения и почему они они были. Тогда, возможно, и мы вам ответим.

> Вы тоже не знаете!

Об изменениях? Это да. Ни о чем таком абсолютно ничего не знаем.